# Spring Filter to add roles to a request from token

Tags: java, spring, authentication, jwt, keycloak

I'm looking for the proper way to add role based authentication where I extract out roles from a JWT.

Ideally, I would like to extract roles from the JWT after authentication has taken place. This will work by inspecting the web token for some fields related to the roles which we are getting from our authentication system, keycloak.

My question is: is it possible to append roles to a request and then use http configuration to require one of these extracted roles?

Below is some relevant code that will help explain what I'm doing.

In my `WebSecurityConfigurer`, I make the access token available, scoped per request.

```
@Bean
@Scope(scopeName = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public AccessToken accessToken() {
    try {
        HttpServletRequest request =
            ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes())
                .getRequest();
        return ((KeycloakSecurityContext) ((KeycloakAuthenticationToken) request
            .getUserPrincipal())
            .getCredentials()).getToken();
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then I override some of the configuration of the http in the `configure` method.

```
http
// Disable session management
.sessionManagement()
.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
.and()
// Allow calls to OPTIONS
.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
.and()
// Authenticate every other call
.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
.and()
.csrf().disable();
```

Ideally, what I'd like to achieve is something like:

```
http.antMatchers("/foo").hasRole("jwt_extracted_role")
```

I am currently creating custom filters which extract roles from the token and then check for the correct roles, but this is maybe more cumbersome than it needs to be.

Any pointers on which methods of which configuration classes I should be looking to override to extract the roles from the request's, and add them to the request?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by overriding the `KeycloakAuthenticationProvider` and providing my override class as a bean in the `WebSecurityConfig`. My class is below:

```
public class ResourceAwareAuthenticationProvider extends KeycloakAuthenticationProvider {
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
          ... here I add granted authorities from the token's credentials ...
    }
}
```

Then in my `class WebSecurityConfigurer extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` I override the AuthenticationProvider:

```
@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return new ProviderManager(Lists.newArrayList(new ResourceAwareAuthenticationProvider()));
}
```

This allows me to do configuration like:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/**").hasAuthority("my-resource-authority")
```

Comment: Out of curiosity what did you miss from the Keycloak Spring Security Adapter ? Out of the box you can already do `.antMatchers("/products*").hasRole("user")`

Comment: The roles which Spring grabbed were incomplete. In my `ResourceAwareAuthenticationProvider` class, I added more roles than what the framework provided.